# Specify Select-Object Details at Runtime

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm using `Get-WmiObject` to dynamically query an SCCM namespace using the following construct:

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName <SCCM Server> -Namespace Root\SMS\SITE_<ID> -Query $query -Credential $credential
```

Is there a way to allow the `Select-Object` details to be specified at runtime? I tried the following with no luck:

```
$properties = Read-Host 'Set Select-Object Properties'
...
$wmi | select $select | Export-Csv ${ENV:USERPROFILE}\Desktop\$filename.csv
```

All it does is return exactly what I typed into the second row of the CSV with no results. Whenever I hard code the properties into the select statement, it works without issues.

Here is a [Gist with the full script signature](https://gist.github.com/JaimeStill/1418d9681d68f90fa0e538d636c68da2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Properties to be an array. You could do this which would allow the user to specify either a space or comma separated list.

```
$properties = (Read-Host 'Set Select-Object Properties') -split ' +|, *'
```

Comment: This worked perfect! Thanks! I'll accept as answer as soon as it will let me.